# Swift extract string between strings using regex

Tags: swift, regex

I found this code online

```
let sample = "#This is an [hello] amazing [world]"
let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "#(.*?)\\[.+?\\]", options: [])
let matches = regex!.matches(in: sample, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, sample.count))
for match in matches {
    let r = (sample as NSString).substring(with: match.range)
    print(r)
}
```

**Current output**

```
#This is an [hello]
```

**expected output**

```
hello
```

How can I extract only the needed text?

**NOTE**

In my case there could be multiple square brackets. See `"[anotherWorld] #This is an [hello] amazing [world]"`. I need the text between the square brackets which is immediately next to `#somerandomtext`. In given sample I need `hello` only

Comment: Your regex is correct. Just a little amendment needed. Check [**this.**](https://regex101.com/r/WWx7Mp/2) Does it help?

Comment: @Mandy8055 How to use the `$1` thing in swift?

Comment: Perhaps [**rangeAt(1)**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstextcheckingresult/1416732-rangeat). Check the working example in this answer. Does it help?

Comment: @Mandy8055. Thanks it works. What is `$0` and `$1`?

Comment: It is the captured group numbers. In javascript we use `$` for captured groups. In many languages we use ```\\``` for captured groups, etc. In swift we use `rangeAt(group number)` function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a capture group to get the text between specific characters.

The pattern

```
"#[^\[]+\[([^\]]+)\]"
```

searches for a `#` then for one or more characters which are not `[` `([^\[]+)`then a `[` (`\[`) then it captures `()` one or more characters which are not `]` (`[^\]]+`) and finally it searches for a `]` (`\]`).

```
let sample = "#This is an [hello] amazing [world]"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:  #"#[^\[]+\[([^\]]+)\]"#)
if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: sample, range: NSRange(sample.startIndex..., in: sample)) {
    let range = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: sample)!
    let result = String(sample[range])
    print(result)
}
```

Your way to create an `NSRange` and the bridge to `NSString` are bad practices. There are dedicated APIs to handle `NSRange`

Comment: Thanks. Almost correct. I want `hello` only. I dont need 'world'. `This is an` is an random text.

Comment: String between `#` and `[` is random.

Comment: Please see the edit. The beginning of the string is irrelevant.

Comment: @vadian you can avoid using backslash on your regex patterns using `#"whatever"#` in this case `#"\[([^\]]+)\]"#`

Comment: In my case there could be multiple square brackets. See `"[anotherWorld] #This is an [hello] amazing [world]"`. I need the text between the square brackets which is immediately next to `#somerandomtext`. In given sample I need `hello` only

Answer (score 0):

If there should not be a `#` or `[` or `]` after matching the `#` and the wanted match from `[...]`, you could make the pattern a bit more restrictive extending the negated character class and use a capturing group:

```
#[^#\]\[]+\[([^\]\[]+)\]
```

*In parts*

- `#` Match a `#` char
- `[^#\]\[]+` [Negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), match 1+ times any char except `#` `[` `]`
- `\[` Match `[`

  - `(` Capture **group 1**
  - `[^\]\[]+` match 1+ times any char except `[` `]`
- `)` Close group
- `\]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/agWkng/1)

Answer (score 0):

The regex approach it is already answered so I will post a native Swift approach:

```
let string = "[anotherWorld] #This is an [hello] amazing [world]"
if let hashTag = string.firstIndex(of: "#"),
    let openBracket = string[hashTag...].firstIndex(of: "["),
    let closedBracket = string[openBracket...].firstIndex(of: "]") {
    let substring = string[string.index(after: openBracket)..<closedBracket]
    let result = String(substring)
    print(result)  // "hello\n"
}
```

---

String manipulation in Swift is not very Swifty but you can extend Collection and create some `SubSequence` methods to make your life easier:

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {

    func firstIndex(after element: Element) -> Index? {
        guard let index = firstIndex(of: element) else { return nil }
        return self.index(after: index)
    }

    func subSequence(from element: Element) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let index = firstIndex(of: element) else { return nil }
        return self[index...]
    }
    func subSequence(after element: Element) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let index = firstIndex(after: element) else { return nil }
        return self[index...]
    }

    func subSequence(upTo element: Element) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let index = firstIndex(after: element) else { return nil }
        return self[..<index]
    }
    func subSequence(upThrough element: Element) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let index = firstIndex(of: element) else { return nil }
        return self[...index]
    }

    func subSequence(from element: Element, upTo: Element) -> SubSequence? {
        guard
            let lower = firstIndex(of: element),
            let upper = self[lower...].firstIndex(of: upTo)
        else { return nil }
        return self[lower..<upper]
    }
    func subSequence(from element: Element, upThrough: Element) -> SubSequence? {
        guard
            let lower = firstIndex(of: element),
            let upper = self[lower...].firstIndex(of: upThrough)
        else { return nil }
        return self[lower...upper]
    }

    func subSequence(after element: Element, upTo: Element) -> SubSequence? {
        guard
            let lower = firstIndex(after: element),
            let upper = self[lower...].firstIndex(of: upTo)
        else { return nil }
        return self[lower..<upper]
    }
    func subSequence(after element: Element, upThrough: Element) -> SubSequence? {
        guard
            let lower = firstIndex(after: element),
            let upper = self[lower...].firstIndex(of: upThrough)
        else { return nil }
        return self[lower...upper]
    }
}
```

---

Now you can get any subsequence between two elements (in the String case a `Substring` between two characters):

```
let string = "[anotherWorld] #This is an [hello] amazing [world]"
let subString = string.subSequence(after: "#")?.subSequence(after: "[", upTo: "]")  // "hello"
```